# postgres analyze settings for skewed data and varying table sizes

Tags: postgresql

I try to set the autovacuum analyze settings for tables on our systems, but I fail to find good ones. Let me give an example:

Let's say we have a table `customer orders` with a column `customer` on a SaaS-system. The table has many million rows for a variety of `customer`s. When a new `customer` starts having orders, e.g. its first 7000, there was likely no analyze of the table yet so the planner picks a wrong plan for queries on that new customer. So this would indicate that we should set our autonanalyze settings like so:

```
ALTER TABLE customer_orders SET (
   autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = 0,
   autovacuum_analyze_threshold = 1000
);
```

That would likely do the trick. But we use the same table `customer orders` on smaller SaaS-systems as well, where this would mean that there is no analyze at all until 1000 rows are in the table which would cause bad query plans there. For these smaller systems good settings could be:

```
ALTER TABLE customer_orders SET (
   autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = 0.01,
   autovacuum_analyze_threshold = 50
);
```

What seems to be missing is a parameter `autovacuum_analyze_upper_limit` that I can set to 1000 so that I can have settings such as

```
ALTER TABLE customer_orders SET (
   autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = 0.01,
   autovacuum_analyze_threshold = 50,
   autovacuum_analyze_upper_limit = 1000
);
```

So the actual analyze threshold would move from 50 to 1000 in a speed of 0.01.

Obvioulsy I made this parameter up. How can I solve this? I see no way to set the analyze settings for my scenario. Do I really need a scheduled job that daily checks the size of the tables and then when the table gets too large switches the analyze settings from 50/0.01 to 0/1000?

Comment: It might help to see an example of a bad query plan, and then of the good plan after ANALYZE has happened.